# My Pandigital To Roman Number not working

Tags: c#, roman-numerals

I have to make a C# program where I make the Roman numbers from the digitals I type in. For some reason I cannot get the code to give me a value when I type in.

```
namespace RomaiSzam

    class ToRomanNumber
    {
        string s = "";

        public string ToRoman(int number)
        {

            if ((number < 0) || (number > 3999))
            {
                s = s + "Invalid input";
            }
            if (number < 1) return s;
            if (number >= 1000) { s = s + "M"; ToRoman(number - 1000); }
            if (number >= 900) { s = s + "CM"; ToRoman(number - 900); }
            if (number >= 500) { s = s + "D"; ToRoman(number - 500); }
            if (number >= 400) { s = s + "CD"; ToRoman(number - 400); }
            if (number >= 100) { s = s + "C"; ToRoman(number - 100); }
            if (number >= 90) { s = s + "XC"; ToRoman(number - 90); }
            if (number >= 50) { s = s + "L"; ToRoman(number - 50); }
            if (number >= 40) { s = s + "XL"; ToRoman(number - 40); }
            if (number >= 10) { s = s + "X"; ToRoman(number - 10); }
            if (number >= 9) { s = s + "IX"; ToRoman(number - 9); }
            if (number >= 5) { s = s + "V"; ToRoman(number - 5); }
            if (number >= 4) { s = s + "IV"; ToRoman(number - 4); }
            if (number >= 1) { s = s + "I"; ToRoman(number - 1); }
            return s;

        }
  }
```

namespace RomaiSzam

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the number");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ToRomanNumber tr = new ToRomanNumber();
        string opt = tr.ToRoman(num);
        Console.WriteLine(opt);

    }
}
```

Here is the code. What is the problem?

Comment: Its simple, what if your number was 30, you only pass that set if "IFs" once... so you would get X ..

Comment: Your code is entering to much IF statements. Use switch instead of if.

Comment: @S.Petrosov There is no `switch` for `>=`

Comment: Would be nice if you gave an example of input and output, and what output you would expect in that case, and also what steps you have taken to try to solve your problem.

Comment: As this sounds like homework, do you need recursion or do you need to just to get the right answer

Comment: The right anwser. Also thank you everyone for spending your time helping me. I started learning C# 3 weeks ago, and I've missed half a year of the course because I changed school, so I have a lot to do. I'm sorry about my messy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You are cascading through all the various `if`s... You shouldn't...

This is probably the minimum logical change you'll need to make it work.

```
class ToRomanNumber
{
    string s = "";

    public string ToRoman(int number)
    {

        if ((number < 0) || (number > 3999))
        {
            s = s + "Invalid input";
        }
        if (number < 1) return s;
        if (number >= 1000) { s = s + "M"; ToRoman(number - 1000); return s; }
        if (number >= 900) { s = s + "CM"; ToRoman(number - 900); return s; }
        if (number >= 500) { s = s + "D"; ToRoman(number - 500); return s; }
        if (number >= 400) { s = s + "CD"; ToRoman(number - 400); return s; }
        if (number >= 100) { s = s + "C"; ToRoman(number - 100); return s; }
        if (number >= 90) { s = s + "XC"; ToRoman(number - 90); return s; }
        if (number >= 50) { s = s + "L"; ToRoman(number - 50); return s; }
        if (number >= 40) { s = s + "XL"; ToRoman(number - 40); return s; }
        if (number >= 10) { s = s + "X"; ToRoman(number - 10); return s; }
        if (number >= 9) { s = s + "IX"; ToRoman(number - 9); return s; }
        if (number >= 5) { s = s + "V"; ToRoman(number - 5); return s; }
        if (number >= 4) { s = s + "IV"; ToRoman(number - 4); return s; }
        if (number >= 1) { s = s + "I"; ToRoman(number - 1); return s; }
        return s;

    }
}
```

**note that it is quite ugly how you wrote it**. Using an instance variable `s` like this is giving me the goosebump.

At least you should do it `static`, like this:

```
class ToRomanNumber
{
    public static string ToRoman(int number)
    {
        if ((number < 0) || (number > 3999))
        {
            return "Invalid input";
        }
        if (number >= 1000) { return "M" + ToRoman(number - 1000); }
        if (number >= 900) { return "CM" + ToRoman(number - 900); }
        if (number >= 500) { return "D" + ToRoman(number - 500); }
        if (number >= 400) { return "CD" + ToRoman(number - 400); }
        if (number >= 100) { return "C" + ToRoman(number - 100); }
        if (number >= 90) { return "XC" + ToRoman(number - 90); }
        if (number >= 50) { return "L" + ToRoman(number - 50); }
        if (number >= 40) { return "XL" + ToRoman(number - 40); }
        if (number >= 10) { return "X" + ToRoman(number - 10); }
        if (number >= 9) { return "IX" + ToRoman(number - 9); }
        if (number >= 5) { return "V" + ToRoman(number - 5); }
        if (number >= 4) { return "IV" + ToRoman(number - 4); }
        if (number >= 1) { return "I" + ToRoman(number - 1); }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
string str = ToRomanNumber.ToRoman(5);
```

And I consider it still to be a little ugly because it is recursive... Using recursivity for this is .... bleah :-)

I would normally write it like:

```
class ToRomanNumber
{
    public static string ToRoman(int number)
    {
        if ((number < 0) || (number > 3999))
        {
            return "Invalid input";
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (number > 0)
        {
            if (number >= 1000) { sb.Append("M"); number -= 1000; }
            else if (number >= 900) { sb.Append("CM"); number -= 900; }
            else if (number >= 500) { sb.Append("D"); number -= 500; }
            else if (number >= 400) { sb.Append("CD"); number -= 400; }
            else if (number >= 100) { sb.Append("C"); number -= 100; }
            else if (number >= 90) { sb.Append("XC"); number -= 90; }
            else if (number >= 50) { sb.Append("L"); number -= 50; }
            else if (number >= 40) { sb.Append("XL"); number -= 40; }
            else if (number >= 10) { sb.Append("X"); number -= 10; }
            else if (number >= 9) { sb.Append("IX"); number -= 9; }
            else if (number >= 5) { sb.Append("V"); number -= 5; }
            else if (number >= 4) { sb.Append("IV"); number -= 4; }
            else if (number >= 1) { sb.Append("I"); number -= 1; }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

so with a cycle.

Comment: Just returning ToRoman(number-n) instead of calling it also works.

Comment: @Martheen I wanted to use the useless `s` instance variable... I was writing a `static` version of the code without the `s` variable.

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of `if` looks *ugly*, they are *difficult* to read and debug; I suggest *extracting* model from the code:

```
// Dictionary sorted in descending order -left.CompareTo(... 
private static SortedDictionary<int, string> romans = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(
  Comparer<int>.Create((left, right) => -left.CompareTo(right))) {

  {1000,  "M"}, 
  { 900, "CM"},  
  { 500,  "D"},  
  { 400, "CD"},
  { 100,  "C"},
  {  90, "XC"},
  {  50,  "L"},
  {  40, "XL"},
  {  10,  "X"},
  {   9, "IX"},   
  {   5,  "V"},
  {   4, "IV"},
  {   1,  "I"},
};
```

And then a simple loop:

```
  public static string ToRoman(int number) {
    if (number < 0 || number > 3999) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (number > 0) {
      var item = romans
        .Where(pair => pair.Key <= number)
        .First();

      number -= item.Key; 
      sb.Append(item.Value);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
```

Tests:

```
  Console.WriteLine(ToRoman(2999));
  Console.WriteLine(ToRoman(2347));
  Console.WriteLine(ToRoman(432));
```

Output

```
  MMCMXCIX  
  MMCCCXLVII
  CDXXXII
```

Comment: Using a `Dictionary<>` in that way is morally wrong... You should use a `Dictionary<>` if you can use its O(1) search. Use a `List<Tuple<>>` (or a `List<KeyValuePair<>>`), and you won't even need the `OrderBy`

Comment: @xanatos: partially agree; but my reasons are: `Dictionary<int, string>` (instead of `List<Tuple<int, string>>`) is a safier in the context (key can't be duplicated and that's why typos like `{9, "XC"}` instead of `{90, "XC"}` are easier to ditect); `{90, "XC"}` is easier to read than `new Tuple<int, string>(90, "XC")`; I's rather not remove `OrderByDescending` in both cases (Dictionary or List) in order to be allowed to organize the model in *different* ways, e.g. `{1000, "M"}, {100, "C"}... {500, "D"}, ... {5, "V"}`

Comment: The truth is that I would have used a `Dictionary<>` too (but note that you can write `Tuple.Create(90, "XC")`), but I wouldn't have posted it on SO :-) Probably a `SortedDictionary<>` would be better (so that you wouldn't have to sort it every time)

Comment: @xanatos: Nice idea! Thank you, `SortedDictionary` is indeed a better choice